# Bell ring on mapping <c-/>

Tags: key-bindings

This is the problem. I want to use  in my mapping but it causes a bell to ring every time I press on it, no matter what I mapped it to.

For example:

```
nmap <c-/> y
```

I am on nvim-qt.

PS tried all of these and still happens:

```
set noerrorbells visualbell t_vb=
set noeb vb t_vb=
autocmd GUIEnter * set visualbell t_vb=
```

Comment: Update, mapping BS and ctrl / in terminal contradict where ctrl / interprets as BS.

Answer (score 1):

On my setup (Vim 8.1.2102, Ubuntu, Gnome-Terminal, german keyboard), `<C-/>` is equivalent to `<C-7>` and `<C-_>`.

I opened a new buffer, changed to insert mode and hit `<C-v>` followed by `<C-/>` and it inserted `^_` (displayed in blue). The same input is created for `<C-v><C-7>` and `<C-v><C-_>`.

So I used the following:

```
nmap <C-_> p
```

Now `<C-_>` acts like `p`. But also `<C-/>` and `<C-7>` works like `p`.

Comment: I set allowrevins with no apparent difference

Comment: @eyalkarni Reevaluated my test and rewrote the answer. Lessons learned: Reevaluate the test case in a new Vim before writing an answer. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The environments are very much different. It was a good try.